# How to run cucumber test cases in Linux centos without using Intellij

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, centos, cucumber, build.gradle

I have cucumber test cases with gradle build and can run them through intellij in windows 10. ( able to run .bat file by picking the path from intellij)

Question. ## Please help me on how to run a specific cucumber test scenario in Linux centos? ##

Is there a way of running the cucumber test scenario by a file in Linux Centos?

Comment: If you're using gradle you can use the gradle plugin and run a test from the cli through gradle

https://github.com/tsundberg/gradle-cucumber-runner/

Answer (score 0):

You can run cucumber from the command prompt. How you do this will depend on what language version for cucumber you are using.

Have a look at https://cucumber.io/docs to find info for your specific platform.